# Ajax Calendar Extender Position is not working in SharePoint Webpart

Tags: user-controls, ajax

I am using Ajax Calendar Extender, but it is not pop up next to textbox, it is appearing int the middle of the page.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dtEnginerring" runat="server" ToolTip="Select Date" > </asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="dtEnginerring_Calendarextender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
    TargetControlID="dtEnginerring" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" 
    PopupPosition="BottomLeft">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: Have you tried not using the PopupPosition property? Most examples i find using this control in SharePoint leaves that one out of the tag.

Comment: did you put it in update panel ? and also did you included script manager ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out by css. It works...

```
.ajax__calendar
    {
        position: fixed !important;
    }
```